# execute a recipe before another recipe in yocto

Tags: yocto

Let's say we have recipe 'A' and 'B' which each one of them install some binaries on the target image. But in run time of image, the binary is resulted of 'A' is depending on the existing of the binary resulted from 'B' . I can make both binaries exist if i just did

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " A B"
```

And this works fine. But what i want is making recipe 'A' calls recipe 'B' in any case so the user doesn't need to be appear that 'A' needs 'B' to run on the image. for example, he does only

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " A"
```

what should i do in recipe 'A' to make this effect ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `B` is a library, adding `DEPENDS += "B"` is enough.

If `B` is an application, you should instead add `RDEPENDS_${PN} += "B"` in the `A` recipe, in order to add a runtime dependency.